# Is "automotive" grade always better?

Tags: automotive, reliability

I'm working on the parts list for a number of designs for low-voltage (24 VDC) industrial circuits that have no special safety requirements: so long as they don't catch fire no one could be hurt nor property damaged.  But they will be used in environments where replacement is expensive, as they are sealed into a more expensive larger unit, and they are in a remote location far away so flying an engineer there to do the refit is very expensive.  So replacing a £10 unit might cost several thousand if it fails in service.  If the best parts were 10% or 20% more expensive, for our number of units, it's easily much cheaper than a single failure in the field.  (Ignoring for the present purposes downtime and reputational costs.) *Edit to add: these units are exposed to weather, and the overwhelming majority of failures in the field are moisture ingress, a small amount of DOA.  We have ten year failure rate data, and have good approaches for housing etc.*

To maximise reliability I was thinking about increasing margins in general: closer tolerance components, thicker tracks on the PCB etc, extra headroom in the power supply, extra temperature range parts, longer soak test, and so on.

I don't have experience of automotive (nor aerospace, nuclear, medical etc) industries, but was considering using the best available parts, within reason.

As far as I've been able to find out, all the AEC Q100 (101, 200) ratings are about reducing the number of failed devices, but they should perform exactly the same.

**Assuming cost margins are acceptable, and performance is within spec, is there ever a reason to prefer an ordinary-grade part over an equivalent automotive-grade one?**

*Edited to clarify: I'm trying to understand if there are any negatives at all to automotive-grade parts other than price.*

*Edited again to clarify: Our starting point is reputable manufacturer via reputable distributor, such as Microchip/ST/Vishay etc and Mouser/Digikey/Arrow etc.  We are not looking at parts via Ebay or Alibaba.  We haven't looked at milspec and aerospace parts because a) they don't appear to be available through our channels, and b) are assumed to be way out of the price we're working to.  Hence this question is focussed on automotive grade which is easily available and has a premium of 10%-100% for the parts we're looking at.*

For a concrete example [ATMEGA328PB-ABTVAO](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega328PB-Automotive-Data-Sheet-40001980B.pdf) versus [ATmega328PB-AN](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/40001906C.pdf).  Same package, reel size, temperature range (-40C to +105C), automotive part is about 8.5% more expensive (whole reels, manufacturer's web site prices).  It is given as having a more conservative voltage (2.7 V vs 1.8 V) and maximum clock (16 MHz vs 20 MHz).  My understanding is it's from the identical design, but with better testing and more conservative promises in order to minimise, ideally to zero, the number of parts which go outside spec?

The automotive part's datasheet has only the following to say:

> **7. Automotive Quality Grade** The devices have been manufactured according to the most stringent requirements of the international
> standard ISO/TS 16949. This data sheet contains limit values extracted from the results of extensive
> characterization (temperature and voltage).
> The quality and reliability have been verified during regular product qualification as per AEC-Q100 grade
> 2 (–40°C to +105°C).  (Datasheet p20)

*Edited to add: some commenters have said automotive grade has better certified temperature range; note that is not the case for this particular part, where both the industrial -N unit and the automotive part have the same temperature range.  Which is why I'm asking about what exactly "automotive" might imply, in general.*

Comment: IMM, the big thing about automotive grade parts is that their performance is specified over a wider temperature than are commercial or industrial parts, but not as wide a temp range as military grade parts, typically -55 deg C to +125 deg C.

Comment: Automotive grade parts also do not (I think) go through the quality control process as do military components.

Comment: What method, or do you have a method, of predicting the reliability of your system in the field?

Comment: And the "best" available parts are space grade semiconductors, passives, PWBs, connectors, etc.  But I doubt they would fit within your budget.

Comment: @SteveSh many thanks for comments.  Predicting reliability: units are exposed to weather, primary cause of failure is water ingress followed by corrosion; we have ten year curves of failures/month.  We predict "better than previous", nothing more numeric I'm afraid..  The failure cost multipliers are approx 1,000x not 1,000,000x, and usage is terrestrial, so we aren't considering radiation hardening and whatever.

Comment: So then sounds like you need to focus on improving environmental protection.  I don't see where the extended temp range for automotive parts buys you much.  Water-tight packages, conformal coating on boards, better connectors, enhances plastic parts (you probably don't want ceramic hermetic packages because of cost), etc.

Comment: @SteveSh thanks again for comments: my question isn't about where to focus, we're clear that the number one issue is weatherproofing.  My question is very clearly about automotive grade: "Assuming cost margins are acceptable, and performance is within spec, is there ever a reason to prefer an ordinary-grade part over an equivalent automotive-grade one?"

Comment: Like I commented below, NO.  Go with the best that fits within your cost constraints.

Comment: That's much clearer and honestly very helpful, thank you.

Comment: You are worried about a few parts the automotive now has thousands of parts in a car and they make millions of cars. They were working with parts per billion years back, not sure where it is today. Consider a $0.01 item failing in a car what the cost is to replace it. Place that in one of the worst electrical environments available over an extreme temperature range with all types of transients etc quality keeps them in business. Mil is about 125C tops while I worked with 175 C in automotive. The automotive requirements are harder to meet then military but do not have the paper requirements.

Comment: Quality vendors are better.  Cheap Cheese  "automotive grade" part < TRW non-automotive grade part.   **Nobody ever got fired for buying IBM**.  (i.e. the guy who just robotically buys all quality manufacturer stuff without thinking about shaving cost by going with unproven brands, is able to successfully blame the reliable manufacturer when it fails).

Comment: @gil thanks for your comment.  I think with our numbers and manufacturing and installation practices it would be almost impossible to ever distinguish chip failure and say, overheating during soldering.  Very helpful your comment about tougher spec than mil but easier bureaucracy.

Comment: Not about quality, but AEC QXXX also imposes minimum lifetime for how long the component will be available from the manufacturer.

Comment: @winny "minimum lifetime of availability":  that is extremely importand to understand (and I didn't know it) thank you.

Comment: @jonathanjo That's a better wording for it. Thank you.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica many thanks for your comment.  Very good point about high quality manufacturers and distributors, but we're actually only considering parts from good reputable sources to start with.  Thankfully in my clients' environments we're not looking for people to blame if things go wrong, we're looking to improve our product.  (What is "cheese" and "TRW"?)

Comment: @jonathanjo Are the DOA units something that could be prevented at the factory?

Comment: @jonathanjo You can get gel-filled connector boxes (q.v.) - maybe you could use that same gel to prevent moisture ingress. That's more of a damp-environment thing than automotive, from what I can see.

Comment: Just a note: the automotive testing for the most part is considered destructive so those parts do not appear in vehicles. These tests validate the processes and yes other parts also run on these processes. These are validation tests, they are additional tests run during production. The qualification process can take several years depending on what it is. Production facilities etc are inspected and approved by the automotive OEMs and regular on a suprise basis.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I estimate about half the DOA are assembly errors (not faults in the circuit we're discussing), half are installation.  We'll certainly find the first when we improve the assembly soak test regime, improving the second might be possible by designing in improved mis-wiring resilience OR realigning commercial terms so that installer pays for units destroyed during installation.

Comment: @AndrewMorton and just to be clear, DOA is a very small problem if it happens when the engineer is installing, just puts in another one.  Failure after installation, after engineer leaves site, is what's very expensive.

Comment: It really depends, sometimes there is a revision of a part that is fixing some issue but has not yet been certified, so you have the choice between the automotive one witht the bug, or the uncertified one without it.

Comment: "primary cause of failure is water ingress followed by corrosion" That's an enclosure problem, not a component problem. Improve your enclosures and your failure rate will drop. You say this is not the focus, but every penny you spend on more expensive parts is a penny you won't spend on better enclosures. Better components are only going to make a difference *after* improving enclosures. Otherwise, it's just a waste of money and the automotive parts will not make a difference regardless of their quality.

Comment: @mast many thanks for your comment.  Indeed I'm sure you're right, but I'm not asking "how do I improve my product?", where I already know which areas are important and which are not.  I'm trying to solve my purchasing problem: having selected a part, do I buy variety A or variety B, both within budget.  And specifically, I'm want to learn about automotive-grade parts -- because I am unfamiliar with them -- and what benefit, if any, they might bring for my designs.  And even more specifically, are there any negatives, _other than money_, to automotive-grade parts.

Comment: @jonathanjo - Sounds like you need to dig into the relevant documents that delineate the qual process for automotive parts.  I can tell you the differences, or point you to the relevant documents, that detail the differences between Commercial, '883B, JAN Class B, QML Level Q., Class S, and QML Level V (from lowest to highest), but I don't know where automotive grade parts fall along that spectrum  Probably between Commercial and '883B, if I had to guess.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but if the moisture ingress is humidity/condensation, I discovered this video recently which might be worth investigating. It's basically a small solid state dehumidifier: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Vabq-s62IVM Looks like the part comes from https://www.micro-dehumidifier.com/

Answer (score 22):

It means that the component underwent testing under specific Automotive standards and passed.

It doesn't mean that the non-Automotive component would not pass as well, it just wasn't tested.

If it is exactly the same component, you pay a bit extra for the automotive qualified component to compensate the manufacturer for paying for the testing, and you get a certificate that you can show to your customer. If your customer doesn't require the certificate, then buy the exact same component, not certified, and save a bit of money.

If it is not exactly the same component, then the automotive certified one is more reliable when used under the challenging automotive environment. But, if your product does not experience that same environment as the automotive one, then that certification doesn't necessarily tell you whether that component will survive longer in your product's environment or not.

EDIT:

> are there any negatives, other than money?"

Possibly: an Automotive Qualified component that does not address issues that are not an issue in the automotive environment, such as low atmospheric pressure, deep sea pressure, ionizing radiation, or strong EMI, may actually be less reliable than a non Automotive Qualified component when used in environments other than automotive. For example, a wire-wound resistor (not Automotive Qualified ) may perform better in a nuclear application than a metal film resistor that is Automotive Qualified.

(Unlikely, but possible.)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  My question is not "Will the automotive part perform better", my question is "If the automotive part is (effectively) the same price, would we ever choose the non-automotive grade?" If there were more tests on the production line, for example, that would be a benefit, not in performance, but in reduced probability of failure.

Comment: ISO/TS 16949 and its referenced ISO 9001:2008 are just quality management systems. Neither one of them dictate or specify exactly what goes into enhancing the "quality" of a component, which seems to be what you're interested in.

Comment: Parts with a lesser pedigree than automotive grade (commercial, industrial) have a lower guaranteed operating temperature range.

Comment: @SteveSh I've been part of ISO 9001 teams and yes indeed, you have to look at them individually to see what  they mean (if your Q process says "on finding a fault you retire to nearest pub and talk about the problems until closing" AND you do it, then you're fully compliant!  My main thing is making sure I've understood automotive grade properly.  Extra testing would be a benefit; extra temperature would be a benefit.  In our application, we probably we get more benefit from better PCB than better chips.  (Better housing, better sealing not my problem today.)

Comment: @jonathanjo > "My question is not ...  my question is ... ". I think I answered your actual question in the 3rd paragraph. To paraphrase: if your application is like automotive = qualified is worth it;  if your application is NOT like automotive = there's no telling.

Comment: @DavideAndrea thanks.  I edited my question to emphasise my question is about "are there any negatives, _other than money_?"  It's clear that benefits-in-auto-environment might or might not translate to benefits in other environments.

Comment: @jonathanjo - thank you for the clarification. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: To clarify further: it automotive grade qual might mean that the manufacturer actually performs extra tests on _every single part_ leaving the factory, not just design testing the product. And then after some years when they are confident of production quality, they might just perform random sample tests. So it might very well be the identical part as the industrial grade one and the only difference is testing.

Comment: Very interesting examples.  Just FYI our present applications don't have any of those: "low atmospheric pressure, deep sea pressure, ionizing radiation, or strong EMI", nor significant vibration.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for that: certainly I'd imagine a manufacturer targeting zero-defect production lines would have to do something like that, and it would be a benefit if we knew that each installed part performed as specified at eg top temperature.

Answer (score 13):

In the comments you suggest your failures in the field are largely from moisture ingress, which is not going to be solved by buying "better" chips, so you need to look at preventing / mitigating against the effects of that first. Better sealing, careful venting, conformal coating, gentle heating (EG anti-frost / anti-dew) and simple things like clipping a pack of desiccant inside the enclosure all help keep moisture off your board.

It's worth noting here (ask me how I know) that sealing your enclosure *too well* can result in it gradually pumping itself full of condensation through capillary action over many thermal cycles (be it night-day or just operations of the equipment) which creates a surprising amount of suction and will pull tiny amounts of moisture in through seals, cable glands, even up inside the jackets of cables - small amounts that eventually add up to a puddle in the bottom of the enclosure that can't get out.

Generally automotive grade stuff is designed for higher temperature range which also implies potential for greater thermal cycling, which is a *great* way to crack solder joints and PCB traces etc. through expansion/contraction cycles. That's something you can (again) design to mitigate - not least by not running stuff too hot, so it's never starting from freezing cold and suddenly heating up massively, for example. Again, a small low-power heater circuit in the enclosure can knock the extremes off this as well as discouraging condensation / humidity.

There's also the question of vibration, which I don't see explicitly stated in your question or indeed mentioned in the automotive components datasheets... but I'm willing to bet manufacturers slapping automotive ratings on chips are at least aware of that aspect & will have tested against it.

Anyway - *all this said*, for an application such as yours, unless there's a huge price difference I would be buying the AEC-Q rated versions of components if they're available just as it's an easy shorthand for "should be pretty reliable", it tells you someone bothered to think about it & do some tests / qualifications on it.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  It's *certain* the majority of problems are moisture ingress, but we know what we're doing with that.  you certainly see what you're describing with architectural luminaires, where the thermal cycling sucks in from everywhere and never pushes moisture out.  "Ask me how I know"..  Okay!  How do you know?

Comment: A very similar way to how you know ;)

Comment: Vibration caused issues are usually due to improper attachment of the part to the board, and not due to the part itself.

Comment: @SteveSh - true for most components, although some case designs will enjoy vibrations less than others and the lack of an automotive-qualified version may hint that it's not the best choice.

Comment: FYI: our present project has no significant vibration issues.

Answer (score 11):

The [answer by Davide Andrea](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/645488/176744) explain exactly what you should expect from an *Automotive* qualified component. I will just emphasise one particular part:

> It means that the component underwent testing under ***specific***
> Automotive standards and passed.
>
> It doesn't mean that the non-Automotive component would not pass as
> well, it just wasn't tested.

---

Look at the tests that an AQ component has to pass to be valid and decide if these tests are close or similar to the test you would want to do for your product or application. Then decide if these AQ tests have some value for you or not. If yes (they reproduce tests you would have to do yourself), then by all mean buy the slightly more expensive component and save on your in house testing.

As a real life example:
My company was making tools for deep drilling applications, we had to qualify our tools for quite severe environments, particularly for continuous operations at temperature over 150C (~300F), or even over 175C.
Automotive standards could not guarantee that (best they do is 125C) so we had to try and test hundreds of components (over a decade and for multiple products obviously, not for a one off). Basically we had to test ourselve *every* component before it could be admitted in our database of acceptable component. Naturally the AQ components were often the first tested but we also tested industrial and commercial grade.
Over the year that database grew and it become quite a piece of private IP for a company because this is knowledge absolutely unavailable anywhere (well a few other companies have something similar but they spent so much time/money building it that they don't share it willy nilly).

Now I am not telling you that you *have* to do all this testing yourself, but an interesting thing that came out of this component repository is that more than 70% of the parts we ended up using were the commercial grade. We had flash memory rated at 55C which we ran for thousands of hours at 170C without problem (this one had no AQ equivalent to consider anyway). None of our microprocessors were AQ either. Oh, and it wasn't just temperature, our shock and vibrations requirements were also stronger than Automotive standards (moisture wasn't a concern for us so can't comment about that).

So to answer your question: NO, Automotive grade is not always *better*. These components only guarantees you a certain set of specifications and resistances. If the specs you need are different, try to find a standard closer to your needs, and if no such standard exists, then start to think about your own testing.

By the way, our products also end up being tightly enclosed and sent away accross the globe, making servicing extremely difficult. Our way to stop too many rogue products going out the door was to test (for functionality) and then **stress test**, at various stages of the assembly and the final product. With experience, we found that most times the few components which were "flaky" were identified early and replaced before final assembly. This didn't happen so often, but the components actually failing in the field during use were even less so (not counting mechanical damages obviously, which was the largest cause of destructions).

Comment: That is extremely helpful, thank you.  Now I'm thinking about appropriate stress tests, which will probably be running in an oven and running with high input voltage.

Comment: @jonathanjo Thanks, I even considered moving that paragraph on top as it was really was saved our bacon for reliability. It might be difficult (not worth it) for a high volume/low value product but for the opposite, low volume/high value product, stress testing is totally worth it. If you said you also have concern about moisture try to incorporate something about it in your stress tests.

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate on your stress tests.  For our case, we soak test  outdoor units in 1m of water so we know they'll survive being left in puddles, flooded zones etc.  For 24 V, input is abs max 40 V, specified at 36V, we'll certainly test at that.  All parts are I think 105C,  step-down converter is 150C (junction).  Units are typically in use 12 hour contunous, daily.  There's a MCU, multiple thermal sensors.  Would you have any recommendation or thoughts on stress tests?

Comment: Burn in at temperatures higher than your max operating temperature (good for weeding out marginal semiconductors & ICs).  For instance, if your max operating temperature is 100 deg C, you might want to burn in at 125 deg C or 150 deg C for several hundred hours.

Comment: Extended temperature range testing is another.  Here you operate/test your unit at temperatures outside (by 10 deg C, say) of its worst case operating temperature range.  In some industries this is called acceptance testing, and it's done on all deliverable units.

Comment: @SteveSh Can I check I've understood your suggestion exactly?  If our parts are all specified at T<sub>J</sub> max op 105°C or higher; real life max ambient is say 50°C (some are in the desert), "acceptance testing" would be at eg junction 115°C for 200 hours?  Estimating the junction temp from measured case temperature and &theta;<sub>JA</sub> from datasheet?  Or testing at ambient=70°C, max working conditions + 20?

Comment: @jonathanjo. The latest, you set your testing limits at your maximum working conditions plus a margin. The spec given in the specsheet helps you to make a component selection, but once a component is selected, you do not have to re-test every element of the specsheet, you only do the tests which are relevant to your application. You might want to create a new question for that topic as testing and stress testing are almost a discipline in itself and will be hard to details in comment fields.

Comment: @hoki thank you that's very helpful, that's what I was intending.makes good sense.

Comment: @jonathanjo - Temperature for acceptance testing (which is done on all units) is typically 11°C above your max operating temperature.  So for your example with a real life max ambient of 50°C, the acceptance test would be done at 61°C ambient.   Burn-is something different, and is usually not done to complete units, but rather at lower levels such a multi-chip-module MCM).

Comment: "you might want to burn in at 125 deg C or 150 deg C" *while bouncing it around for +100k miles*. That's what makes it automotive grade (especially if it's a part GM has put on every single vehicle they've ever made since 1965 - *fleet tested*).  - Spraying a garden hose at it while it ingests whole frozen chickens is for planes. Doing all of that at 3000psi, zero, and everywhere in between is for aerospace. Manufacturer's specs only help you sue them later. Your job is stress testing *the shit* out of it and not taking them at their word.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the testing differences, you might see significant differences in *availability*.

Automotive grade components are designed to sell to automobile manufacturers (or their parts vendors), of which there aren't very many in the broad scope of things.  A large auto group like General Motors would buy enough parts to warrant a production run just for them, and they often order parts directly from the manufacturer.  Once they stop using the part, though, demand almost completely dries up and it's no longer economical to produce the specialized version of that part.  This isn't a problem exclusive to "automotive-grade" components, it also applies to other types of specialty equipment grades (military, aerospace, marine, etc.).  Specialty parts have to undergo special testing, which means lead times can be longer.

For the standard version of the part, demand isn't (generally) concentrated in one or two huge accounts.  It gets bought by a diverse variety of customers of all sizes.  It is *significantly* less likely that demand suddenly drops and the part is discontinued outside its planned and published lifecycle.  Buying direct from the manufacturer is rarer, and you're much more likely to find the parts in stock at your preferred parts vendor.

I often substitute specialty-grade parts when I can't source the standard-grade parts for some reason.  I would definitely hesitate to specify a specialty-grade part as my standard selection, though, unless I actually needed the additional temperature range (or whatever else is different in the specs).  If down the road you have to swap that discontinued specialty part for a standard part that isn't rated to the same level, you risk having to do extensive re-testing and re-qualification on your equipment.  It's generally not a problem the other way around since the replacement is rated to work in all situations where the original one worked.

Comment: Very useful answer, thank you.  The multi-customer issue is very underconsidered, but the recent trends of increased niche-specialisation of parts, with correspondingly smaller numbers of buyers for each, has directly contributed to the current supply chain crisis.  I'm currently designing with maximally-available parts for thsi reason.

Comment: The most important part of your answer is exactly the one about later unavailability.  For example a scenario where manfucturer recalls the auto part but not the standard part.  Would we recall our product?  If we chose the auto part just because "it should be pretty reliable" (per [John U answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/645535) we wouldn't know if the recall was for reasons we cared about or reasons we don't.  **This is an actual non-cost negative**

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would not specify automotive rated parts in most cases if there were cheaper and as (or more) available parts from reliable suppliers that meet all the requirements. The expensive spot checking of large numbers of samples picked from manufacturing lots on a quarterly basis provides some additional assurance, but most unstressed parts are very, very reliable if the design is not deficient in some way.

If there is slack in the maximum BOM cost I would prefer to spend it in places where it will make a difference such as pumping up ratings on *stressed* parts rather than wasting it (and possibly causing availability issues). A power MOSFET that runs cooler and has more voltage rating and better SOA is going to add a lot more to reliability than any change to an ordinary resistor. Also it is possible for purchasing to substitute the automotive parts if the ordinary ones become unavailable.

That said, there are some *features* that were developed for automotive customers that are very nice with or without the rating. The relatively wide temperature range, and 'soft' connections that allow more PCB flexing without MLCC microcrack failures, for example.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful.  What is SOA?

Comment: Safe Operating Area.  A set of curves that tell you how long you can have simultaneous drain voltage and current (as when switching an inductive load or switching slowly to minimize EMI).

Answer (score 4):

This really comes down to a cost/benefit tradeoff - more expensive parts (unit) for better reliability.  I'm going to use US dollars in the example that follows.

Lets say you have $10 unit (you said £10, so this is close) built with industrial grade parts that has a MTBF (mean time between failure) of 1 year, and costs $1,000 to replace in the field.

If you upgrade that unit with parts costing 2X as much, so now the unit costs $20, but you get a 2X improvement in the MTBF to 2 years, your total cost over two years has gone down from $2,020 (replacing 2 units) to $1,040 ( replace 1 unit in 2 years), clearly a cost saving.

What if that 2X reliability improvement required that you use parts that cost 10 times a much as your baseline design?  Your total cost over two years is now $100 (for the unit) + $1,000 (for the replacement trip) for total of $1,100.  This is still an improvement over your baseline design.

So the first thing you need to do is come up with the expected failure rate, or MTBF, for your $10, or whatever the actual cost is, design.

And obviously, things are different if the cost of your base unit $1,000, not $10 like I used.  In that case, it may be cheaper to replace it every year rather than increase the unit cost by 2X.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.  My question isn't about the economics of higher reliability parts / unit prices / N units (no argument with what you've said about that).  My question is about "if the cost is acceptable, would you ever choose the standard over the automotive part".

Comment: I would go with the best quality part that fits in my price target.

Comment: The trouble is that you are assuming that (more $) == (more reliable). Actual experience with the most expensive (space qualified) parts shows this to be untrue. A better assumption is (bigger production volume) == (more reliable), especially when the parts are used in things like cars and computers, whose users are very sensitive to system reliability issues. But there's no magic formula, and neither price nor documents are a reliable guide to reliability.

Comment: @John Doty - No.  I'm assuming that better quality parts == better reliability == higher costs.  If you doubt that, try putting together a mission critical space payload with standard quality parts and see how far that gets you with your customer.

Comment: @SteveSh Been there, done that. HETE-2 and NICER for example. In both these cases, the majority of the parts were industrial or automotive grade. In both of these cases, the parts failures that occurred were of expensive space-qualified parts. ALEXIS (which I wasn't involved with) had a similar experience.

Comment: I've never had a space project where we've been allowed to use automotive/industrial grade parts, unless 1) they were the only viable solution and 2) we put together a program to upscreen those parts.

Comment: @SteveSh That's not a universal experience. And there's quite a bit of lore in the space community that industrial and automotive grade parts have better quality in the real world than space-qualified parts. Upscreening is a racket: I know a guy who did the experiment of sending the rejected and accepted parts through PIND testing a second time. 20% had been rejected the first time, but only 20% of those rejects were rejected twice. 20% of the parts that passed were rejected the second time. In other words, there was no correlation: the test was randomly rejecting/accepting parts.

Comment: @JohnDoty that's extremely interesting!  In passing, where do you buy aero/mil/space parts?  "milspec" at eg mouser is pretty much all connectors, no chips, no passives.  Amp 25D skt ~$200 vs ~$2 for commercial: certainly one can see the incentive for corruption of various kinds.

Comment: @jonathanjo - It's been a while since I've dealt closely with our supply chain.  But in general we purchase mil-aero parts from big US based distributors (like Arrow, Avnet, etc) or directly from the factory.  Note that in many cases mil-aero parts may have 52 week (or longer) lead times.

Comment: @jonathanjo I don't do that job. If the customer wants aerospace parts, it's their problem to find them. As SteveSh says, its either the usual distributors or direct.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the parts may well be identical. The very same controller can be reliable enough for automotive use if you keep the clock below 16 MHz and supply voltage above 2.7V, and at the same time be only consumer-grade at 20 MHz and 1.8V, respectively.

Many automotive-grade parts, however, are **not** the same as their consumer-grade equivalents. Typically, temperature range is wider (a wide temperature range is not that expensive to achieve in a microcontroller, but automotive-grade ELCOs and FETs will actually have a wider range). Anything that could be connected to the battery will have a wider over-voltage margin (12V automotive parts will typically remain operational up to at least 18-20V, and survive up to 25-30V). Again, this doesn't really affect an MCU which needs a regulated low-voltage supply anyway. Larger parts will typically have more expensive pin design, or have more unused pins, in order to cope with mechanical vibrations; but again, a tiny MCU is not heavy enough for its pin design to make a difference in MTBF.

There are also other minor differences, for instance, communication interfaces may have higher noise immunity, and quiescent currents may be substantially lower, so that they don't discharge the battery when not in use.

If high temperatures, vibrations and voltage surges are among your prime failure factors, using automotive parts may be a good idea. Otherwise, the benefit from using such parts will be limited. You might as well use consumer-grade parts and add a large margin on critical characteristics (relevant to your project) yourself.

Comment: Thank you this is extremely helpful too.  Though as I understand it you're saying most benefits-to-automotive are not (in this case) benefits-to-us and are thus don't-cares.  Can you think of any negatives? (Other than cost, which is understood.)

Comment: @jonathanjo Innovation lag would be one drawback. New technologies (e.g. GaN) are introduced in commercial products much earlier than in automotive, to the point a commercial product can technically (ignoring certification aspects) be a better choice even for automotive use.